# Unknown attribute error for parent id, only happening in test

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have TopicList (parent) and Topic (child) models

```
class TopicList < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :topics
    validates :name, presence: true , uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
end

class Topic < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :topic_list
  validates :topic_list_id, presence: true
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
end
```

The schema.rb includes:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20161116031922) do

  create_table "topic_lists", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["name"], name: "index_topic_lists_on_name", unique: true
  end

  create_table "topics", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "source"
    t.integer  "position"
    t.integer  "topic_list_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
    t.index ["name"], name: "index_topics_on_name", unique: true
    t.index ["position"], name: "index_topics_on_position"
    t.index ["topic_list_id"], name: "index_topics_on_topic_list_id"
  end
```

My topic_test.rb starts by creating a new TopicList and building a Topic under it:

```
require 'test_helper'

class TopicTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    @topic_list = TopicList.new(name: "Vocab")
    @topic_list.save
    @topic = @topic_list.topics.build(name: "Topic 1")
  end

  test "should be valid" do
    assert @topic.valid?
  end
end
```

Whenever I run this test, I get the error:

```
ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'topic_list_id' for Topic.
```

But when I try the same sequence in my rails console, it works just fine.

```
Loading development environment (Rails 5.0.0.1)
>> list = TopicList.new(name: "List 1")
=> #<TopicList id: nil, name: "List 1", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
>> list.save
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  TopicList Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "topic_lists" WHERE LOWER("topic_lists"."name") = LOWER(?) LIMIT ?  [["name", "List 1"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "topic_lists" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["name", "List 1"], ["created_at", 2016-11-16 21:23:33 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-11-16 21:23:33 UTC]]
   (11.3ms)  commit transaction
=> true
>> topic = list.topics.build(name: "Topic #1")
=> #<Topic id: nil, name: "Topic #1", source: nil, position: nil, topic_list_id: 3, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
>> topic.valid?
  Topic Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "topics" WHERE LOWER("topics"."name") = LOWER(?) LIMIT ?  [["name", "Topic #1"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> true
>>
```

Every similar question I've found here deals with incorrect CamelCase, snake_case, or plural/single names. I think I've done all that correctly here. What am I missing?

Comment: Is your test database configured correctly? Can you paste the full stack trace of the error?

Answer (score 0):

I ran `rails db:test:load`, and that cleared it up. Not sure why this is needed sometimes but not others.